# An explanation of how the range of a complex function works? Specifically $f(z)=z^2$ for$Re(z)>0$, $Im(z)>0$ and in the first quadrant..

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm going through this complex analysis textbook, and it tells me that the range of the aforementioned function is $Im(w) \geq 0$.  To me, that makes no sense. Could someone explain that, by chance? The complex plane isn't clicking, and I have a feeling these answers are going to make me feel dumb.

To add to this question, I have another problematic question:
Find the range of $h(z)=1/z$ for $0<|z|\leq1$.

The answer, apparently, is $|w|\geq1$. Again, I have no idea how that answer was found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first quadrant, the argument (angle) obeys
$$0<\theta<\frac{\pi}2$$

When you square a complex number, you square its modulus (distance from the origin in the complex plane) and double its angle, due to [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

$$[r\cdot \mathrm{cis}(\theta)]^2=r^2\cdot \mathrm{cis}(2\theta)$$

Therefore, while the range of the modulus stays the same (greater than zero), the argument now obeys
$$0<2\theta<\pi$$

The argument is between zero and $\pi$ for the imaginary part positive (not just non-negative, as you stated). So $Im(z^2)>0$ and your textbook is *almost* correct.

For your added, second question, if $0<|z|\le 1$, then $z$'s argument $\theta$ has no restriction but its modulus is restricted by $0<r\le 1$. Then by De Moivre's theorem,

$$\frac 1z=z^{-1}=r^{-1}\mathrm{cis}(-\theta)$$
so
$$|z^{-1}|=r^{-1}\ge 1$$

We easily see the argument $-\theta$ can be anything, so the range of $h(z)=1/z$ for $0<|z|\le 1$ is indeed $|w|\ge 1$.

Comment: @Rory_Daulton Thanks! That helps a lot an shed some light on this... I'm starting to feel my textbook has a lot of wrong answers.  Do you mind taking a look at my edit?

Comment: This is a good answer, but still, alternatively you could write $z = x + iy$, and examine how $z^2$ (write it) behaves when $x > 0$ and $y > 0$. One of the fascinating things about the complex numbers is that this is really the same thing, or rather, that the De Moivre's formula is a thing.

Comment: @Kekkonen: Your method easily shows how $z^2$ is in the upper half-plane, but it is more difficult to show that everything in the half plane is a square of something in the first quadrant. (I used to play with those ideas in high school.) Plus my method has some obvious generalizations. But you are right that the multiple approaches are fascinating.

Comment: So the answer IS $Im(w) > 0$? Since $w=z^2$?

Comment: Yes, for your first question the answer is that the range is $\mathrm{Im}(w)>0$, for the second the range is $|w|\ge 1$. You could use $z$'s rather than $w$'s: the variable is not important.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rory.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, this is just a matter of solving. Suppose $x \in \mathbb{C}$ is not zero, then $\frac{1}{y} = x \Leftrightarrow y=\frac{1}{x}$. So $x$ will be in the image if and only if $0 < \left | \frac{1}{x} \right | \leq 1$. The first inequality will always hold (why?), while the other can be solved by taking reciprocals, giving $|x| \geq 1$.